# How to use client-side event batching functionality while Sending to Microsoft Azure EventHubs

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I'm dealing with a high throughput application of EventHub. According to the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/), in order to achieve very high throughput from a single sender, then client-side batching is required (without exceeding the 256 KB limit per event).

[Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus brokered messaging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-performance-improvements) suggests Client-side batching for achieving performance improvements. It describes client-side batching is available for queue or topic clients, which enables delaying the sending of messages for a certain period of time, then it transmits the messages in a single batch.

Is client-side batching available in the EventHub client?

Comment: I've tried specifying MessagingFactorySettings,AmqpTransportSettings.BatchFlushInterval without any effect.

Comment: Is there any problem with use of SendBatch and SendBatchAsync methods?

Comment: Please post the code used and a detailed description of the problem, including the full text of any exceptions (ie use Exception.ToString()).  What does "without any effect" mean? Was there an error? Were no messages were sent? Or were the messages sent as individual messages instead of a batch? How did you check?

Comment: Also note that the *batch* can't go beyond 256KB. Did you try to send a larger batch perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ShortAns**: EventHubs is designed to support very-high thruput scenarios - Client-side batching is one of the Key features to enable this. API is [`EventHubClient.SendBatch(IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatch.aspx).

**Long Story**:

The link that you found: [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus brokered messaging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-performance-improvements/) applies to ServiceBus Queues & Topics - which uses a Microsoft Proprietary protocol called - SBMP - and is not an Open Standard. We implemented BatchFlushInterval in that Protocol. This was a while back (guess around 2010) - where [Amqp](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf) protocol wasn't standardized yet. When we started building Azure EventHubs service - [Amqp](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf) is the new Standard protocol for implementing performant messaging solutions and hence, we used [Amqp](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf) as our first-class protocol for Event Hubs. BatchFlushInterval doesn't have any effect in EventHubs ([Amqp](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf)).

`EventHubClient` translates every raw event that you need to send to EventHub into AmqpMessage (refer to Messaging section in the ([Amqp Protocol Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/amqp-core-complete-v1.0.pdf)).

In order to do that, as per the protocol, it adds few extra bytes to each Message. The estimated Size of each Serialized EventData (to AmqpMessage) can be found using the property - [`EventData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.aspx) [`SerializedSizeInBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.serializedsizeinbytes.aspx).

With that background, coming to your scenario: Best way, to achieve very high-thruputs - is to use [`EventHubClient.SendBatch(IEnumerable<EventData>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatch.aspx) api. The contract of this Api is - before invoking `SendBatch` - the caller need to make sure the Serialized Size of this Batch of messages doesn't exceed 256k. Internally, this API converts the `IEnumerable<EventData>` into 1 Single AmqpMessage and sends to EventHub Service. The limit on 1 single AmqpMessage imposed by EventHubs service as-of 4-25-2016 is 256k. Plus, one more detail - when the list of `EventData` are translated to a Single AmqpMessage - `EventHubClient` needs to promote some information into the BatchMessage header - which is common for all of those messages in the batch(info like `partitionKey`). This info. is guaranteed to be a max of 6k.

So, all-in-all, **the caller need to keep track of the aggregate size of all `EventData` in the `IEnumerable<EventData>` and make sure that this falls below 250k**.

---

**EDIT ON 09/14/2017**

WE added [`EventHubClient.CreateBatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdatabatch?view=azureservicebus-4.1.1) API to support this scenario.

There is no more guess work involved in constructing a Batch of `EventData`s. Get an `Empty EventDataBatch` from `EventHubClient.CreateBatch` API and then use `TryAdd(EventData)` api to add events to construct the Batch.

And, finally use `EventDataBatch.ToEnumerable()` to get the underlying events to pass to the `EventHubClient.Send()` API.

[more on Event Hubs...](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Comment: Thank you for the accurate answer I was waiting for and the information for creating a custom implementation.

Comment: Why do you say "*estimated* Size of each Serialized EventData"? How can we get the exact size? If the size of my batch is estimated to be 200KB but it's actually 257KB then I have a problem...

Comment: And if we can't get the exact size, some guarantee about the approximation of `SerializedSizeInBytes` would be great. For example if I knew the approximation was at most 1KB off per event, and I had 10 events, I could stop when I got to 240KB.

Comment: we implemented a helper method to make this easy for the customers - please look at the above answer.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for updating! Note that I do not receive notifications unless you mention me (@OhadSchneider), I just happened to check back and saw this. BTW what's your @microsoft.com alias (I'm an MS employee too)?

Comment: Thanks! I'm ohads BTW :) Say, any thoughts about exposing a static `CreateBatch` overload? Maybe something like `CreateAmqpBatch` since I assume the batch size depends on the transport. Or at least exposing the max AMQP message size constant (`262144L` according to the IL) somewhere so I could call `new EventDataBatch` myself more elegantly?

Comment: @OhadSchneider - client negotiates message size with service every time you create an EventHubClient object. This needs to be passed on to EventDataBatch and hence the non-static factory method...

Comment: @Sreeram interesting, then what is `this.MaxMessageSize = 262144L;` I see when I reflect the code for the `AmqpMessageSender` constructor?

Comment: @OhadSchneider - that's the default value (which is the min.) - It gets overwritten post hand-shake. For instance, if you are on a Dedicated EventHubOffering - this value could be 1MB as well.

Comment: @Sreeram Edit 09/14/2017. When is the best moment to flush the data?
Should we still check for the max size of 256k?

Comment: @Sreeram what about sendbatch in asp.net? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326065/how-can-i-use-azure-event-hub-in-asp-net-websites-to-track-event

Comment: i still received "{"The received message (delivery-id:0, size:265101 bytes) exceeds the limit (262144 bytes) currently allowed on the link."}" after using EventDataBatch

Answer (score 1):

your links are accurate. There are SendBatch and SendBatchAsync methods of Event Hubs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatch.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

There is [a nice article and extension by Paolo Salvatori](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/03/26/how-to-implement-a-partitioned-sendbatch-method-for-azure-service-bus-entities/) as well.

Comment: I require EventHub client functionality similar to ServiceBus Queues & Topics clients, which delay sending of messages for a certain period of time, then they transmit the messages in a single batch (not exceeding 256K). According to [Sreeram](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3277385/sreeram), this functionality has not been implemented in the EventHub client, so a custom implementation is required. Paolo Salvatori's extension could be used for creating batches not exceeding the 256K limit, but the implementation is not accurate unfortunately and MessageSizeExceededException might be thrown.